# Cant call button as Event handler in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a total beginner and I'm about to finish my first website.

But I just cant get the last button to work. Its the simplest task but this one is just not working.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  alert("mailto script loaded!");
})

//eventhandler send-button
$('#send').onclick(function() {
  alert( "Handler has beend called." );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttonsend">
  <button class="button button-pill button-flat-action" id="send">Senden</button>
</div>
```

Can you guys give me a  hint where the problem is?
Thank you very much in advance. I googled everything but i unterstand basically what i need to do. I just cant see where i am going wrong.

Comment: Add the handler code to document ready. change `onclick` to `click`

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery event is called `click` not `onclick`. Change to:

```
$('#send').click(function() {
```

Depending on where the JavaScript is placed on the page, you may need to wrap it in a DOM ready handler.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#send').click(function() {
        alert( "Handler has beend called." );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Aside from putting the handler in the document ready, you should fix your syntax too. You need to use `.on()` to handle an event which is the first parameter to the method. Documentation here: https://api.jquery.com/on/

```
//alert if the js-script is succesfully loaded
$( document ).ready(function() {
    alert("mailto script loaded!");
    //eventhandler send-button
    $('#send').on('click',function() {
        alert( "Handler has beend called." );
    });
})
```

Working Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/5xn5tpq4/

The code in the javascript pane is already wrapped with the ready handler.